# Proper table alignment and rowspan

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following table:

html

```
<table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>    
                <th colspan="3">Special Rates offered to conference participants</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th rowspan="3">Conference</th>
                <th>Overnight stay with breakfast in </th>
                <th>Overnight stay with breakfast in
                </th>                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="no-border"></th>
                <th class="no-border"></th>                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>single room</th>
                <th>double room</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Elite City Resort</td>
                <td>58,00 Euros</td>
                <td>75,00 Euros</td>
            </tr>                
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and css

```
table{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, tr, th{
    border:1px solid black;

}
```

I want the second and third columns in the second line to be like this.

First Line: Overnight stay with
Second line breakfast in (centered)
Third line empty (like new line)
Fourth single room

And the same for third column. I know my code is for three lines, but it gives me to many borders. I want to have no borders between lines and empty line. How can I fix it?

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qg36g/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the borders purely in CSS with no HTML changes needed.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/qg36g/2/)

Try this CSS:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
    border:1px solid black;
}
tr th:not([rowspan]){
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

For the line separation, you can either play with [**the widths**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/qg36g/3/) or use JohnBupits answer above.

Comment: Might need a `<br />` to put _breakfast in_ in the second line.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qg36g/1/).

You could just to this using rowspans on the `<th>` containing `Overnight stay with breakfast in`, like this:

```
...
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th colspan="3">Special Rates offered to conference participants</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3">Conference</th>
            <th rowspan="3">Overnight stay with
                <br /> breakfast in
                <br />
                <br />single room
            </th>
            <th rowspan="3">Overnight stay with
                <br /> breakfast in
                <br />
                <br />double room
            </th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
...
```

Comment: you should probably use the selfclosing `<br />` just for (pedantic-ness) validity :)